# create a file with text and a graph java

Tags: java, file, graph

I'm pretty new to Java and was wondering if it is possible to write a program which will create a file with some text and a simple two-dimensional graph (just a couple of points connected via line in a coordinate system).
I've seen in other posts that each on its own is possible. Is it both together?

Comment: To answer your question: Yes it is possible. But if you are looking for a tutorial SO is not the right site for this kind of questions.

Comment: documentation is in bita yet , so hope one day you will find your solution there

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Could you maybe point me to a site where I can see such a tutorial/documentation? Because googling this problem didn't give me anything.

Answer (score 0):

Read on how to write to a file here: [How to write ...](http://www.programcreek.com/2011/03/java-write-to-a-file-code-example/)
Since you graph is not that big, you can use adjacency matrix Representation. you can read more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20024149/adjacency-matrix-in-java). Read those, and they will give you more pointers to google further.